# Elements in list greater than or equal to elements in other list (without for loop?)

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a list containing 1,000,000 elements (numbers) called x and I would like to count how many of them are equal to or above [0.5,0.55,0.60,...,1]. Is there a way to do it without a for loop?

Right now I have the following the code, which works for a specific value of the [0.5,...1] interval, let's say 0.5 and assigns it to the count variable

```
count=len([i for i in x if i >= 0.5])
```

EDIT: Basically what I want to avoid is doing this... if possible?

```
obs=[]
alpha = [0.5,0.55,0.6,0.65,0.7,0.75,0.8,0.85,0.9,0.95,1]

for a in alpha:
    count= len([i for i in x if i >= a])
    obs.append(count)
```

Thanks in advance
Best, Mikael

Comment: I do not think you can do this without a loop. Even if you tend to use any package that does this for you, it would still be traversing the list behind the scenes using some looping mechanism.

Comment: @unixia. But would it be a *for* loop?

Comment: @MadPhysicist hmm can't say about that.

Comment: Is your list always sorted?

Comment: Is a histogram what you want?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible without loop, but you can sort the array `x` and then you can use `bisect` module ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left)) to locate insertion point (index).

For example:

```
x = [0.341, 0.423, 0.678, 0.999, 0.523, 0.751, 0.7]
    
alpha = [0.5,0.55,0.6,0.65,0.7,0.75,0.8,0.85,0.9,0.95,1]

x = sorted(x)

import bisect

obs = [len(x) - bisect.bisect_left(x, a) for a in alpha]

print(obs)
```

Will print:

```
[5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Note:

`sorted()` has complexity `n log(n)` and `bisect_left()` `log(n)`

Comment: Let's say len(alpha) is m. This means we're looking at O((n + m) log n). OP's original is O(m * n). For m << n, OP wins, but for m ~= n, you win. Same applies to my answer, which is just shorter because of numpy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy and boolean indexing:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array(list(range(100)))
>>> a[a>=50].size
50
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my question is what I should do if I want to find the size of >=50, >=55, ... and so forth  (where I have 50,55,... saved as a list)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: If you are using NumPy already, you can simply do this:

```
import numpy as np

# Make random data
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.binomial(n=20, p=0.5, size=1000000) / 20
bins = np.arange(0.55, 1.01, 0.05)
# One extra value for the upper bound of last bin
bins = np.append(bins, max(bins.max(), x.max()) + 1)
h, _ = np.histogram(x, bins)
result = np.cumsum(h)
print(result)
# [280645 354806 391658 406410 411048 412152 412356 412377 412378 412378]
```

---

If you are dealing with large arrays of numbers, you may considering using [NumPy](https://numpy.org/). But if you are using simple Python lists, you can do that for example like this:

```
def how_many_bigger(nums, mins):
    # List of counts for each minimum
    counts = [0] * len(mins)
    # For each number
    for n in nums:
        # For each minimum
        for i, m in enumerate(mins):
            # Add 1 to the count if the number is greater than the current minimum
            if n >= m:
                counts[i] += 1
    return counts

# Test
import random
# Make random data
random.seed(0)
nums = [random.random() for _ in range(1_000_000)]
# Make minimums
mins = [i / 100. for i in range(55, 101, 5)]
print(mins)
# [0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1.0]
count = how_many_bigger(nums, mins)
print(count)
# [449771, 399555, 349543, 299687, 249605, 199774, 149945, 99928, 49670, 0]
```

Comment: Hi,

My x is given as 

```x=np.random.binomial(n=20, p=0.5,size=1000000)```

Comment: @MikaelOlaiMilhøj The values returned by that function are almost always greater than 1.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include /20

Comment: @MikaelOlaiMilhøj Updated for that random data.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are not using for loop, internal methods use them. But iterates them efficiently.

you can use below function without for loop from your end.

```py
x = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
l = list(filter(lambda _: _ > .5 , x))
print(l)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have never seen the _ before. What is that? (sorry, new to python, as you may have figured out already!)

Comment: @MikaelOlaiMilhøj `_` is a valid parameter name, but it is conventionally used for ignored parameters, it's not recommended if you are actually using its value (see [What is the purpose of the single underscore “_” variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5893163)).

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments, you're ok with using numpy, so use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to simply insert `alpha` into a sorted version of `x`. The indices will be your counts.

If you're ok with sorting `x` in-place:

```
x.sort()
counts = x.size - np.searchsorted(x, alpha)
```

If not,

```
counts = x.size - np.searchsorted(np.sort(x), alpha)
```

These counts assume that you want `x < alpha`. To get `<=` add the keyword `side='right'`:

```
np.searchsorted(x, alpha, side='right')
```

**PS**

There are a couple of significant problems with the line

```
count = len([i for i in x if i >= 0.5])
```

First of all, you're creating a list of all the matching elements instead of just counting them. To count them do

```
count = sum(1 for i in x if i >= threshold)
```

Now the problem is that you are doing a linear pass through the entire array for each alpha, which is not necessary.

As I commented under [@Andrej Kesely's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58961311/2988730), let's say we have `N = len(x)` and `M = len(alpha)`. Your implementation is `O(M * N)` time complexity, while sorting gives you `O((M + N) log N)`. For `M << N` (small `alpha`), your complexity is approximately `O(N)`, which beats `O(N log N)`. But for `M ~= N`, yours approaches `O(N^2)` vs my `O(N log N)`.